# How to upload an image with nativescript-camera and nativescript-background-http on IOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am able to upload a file on android to a C# web api, using `nativescript-camera` with `nativescript-background-http`.

I set the params as follows:

```
  var params = [{ name: "image", filename: fileUri, mimeType: 'application/octet-stream' }];
```

...

And send the request:

```
let request = {
        url: this.API_URL + "/UploadOctetFile",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": accessTokenJson,
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
          "File-Name": imageName
        },  
        description: "{ 'uploading': " + imageName + " }"
      };

      return this.session.multipartUpload(params, request);
```

In android the fileUri is returned in a fairly straight forward manner:

```
takePictrue.then((imageAsset: ImageAsset) => {
```

Then `imageAsset.android` has the file uri that is needed to send the image. However, for ios, `imageAsset.ios` is a PHAsset. To get the file URI, I use the following code:

```
        let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
        let options = new PHImageRequestOptions();
        options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact;
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
```

manager.requestImageForAssetTargetSizeContentModeOptionsResultHandler(imageAsset.ios, { width: 2048, height: 1536 }, PHImageContentModeAspectFill, options, function (result, info) {
            let srcfilePath = info.objectForKey("PHImageFileURLKey").toString();
               ...
        });

In the above: srcfilePath (which I pass as fileUri) is: file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1902.JPG

The image name is then IMG_1902.JPG

However, this uploads an empty file. I'm guessing that I need to change the fileUri or perhaps I should be using a different method to: `requestImageForAssetTargetSizeContentModeOptionsResultHandler`.

I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http/issues/90) to do:

```
 let fileUri = image.fileUri.replace("file://","");
```

and I've tried changing the mime type `"mimeType":"image/jpg"`.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt iOS allows us to access the actual image file, why don't you write the image asset to a temp file and upload that?

Comment: Thanks. I think you might be right. I will give this a go in the next few days and will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam, this might help.  I did the following to handle an iOS user selecting a photo from their gallery for use later in the app (Android is simple and straightforward like in your case, but iOS returns a PHAsset):

```
import { ImageSource } from "image-source";
import { Image } from "tns-core-modules/ui/image";
import { path, knownFolders } from "tns-core-modules/file-system";

//iOS user picks photo...

const iosImg = new ImageSource();
iosImg.fromAsset(myPHAsset).then(imsr => {
  this.counter += 1; //class property to allow unique filenames
  const folder = knownFolders.documents();
  const path2 = path.join(folder.path, `Image${this.counter}.jpg`);
  const saved = imsr.saveToFile(path2, "jpg");
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = path2;
  this.data.changeImage(img); //Ng service to allow use of image in other components
});
```

Links: [{N} docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/image-source#save-image-to-png-or-jpg-file)

[{N} imagepicker #197](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/issues/197#issuecomment-431783669)

[{N} imageUpload code](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload/blob/master/app/main-page.js#L109-L115)